# Why is it so long in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, f#

I have this F# code

```ml
open System

let pisano (n : uint64) = 
    let max = n * n
    let rec pisanoRec prev cur ind =
        if ind < max
        then let mutable ncur = (cur + prev)
                if ncur >= n
                then ncur <- ncur - n
                if cur = uint64 0 && ncur = uint64 1
                then ind + uint64 1
                else pisanoRec cur ncur (ind + uint64 1)
        else  uint64 0

    pisanoRec (uint64 0) (uint64 1) (uint64 0)

let pv = 1953125 // 196925089 // 421051797

let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
sw.Restart()
let v = pisano (uint64 pv) 
sw.Stop()
printfn "Pisano %i "v
printfn ("Time elapsed: %A" sw.Elapsed
```

With VS Code I get

```
Pisano 7812500UL 
Time elapsed: 00:00:00.0505988
```

I tried to translate it in Haskell :

```hs
pisano :: Integer  -> Integer 
pisano n =
    pisanoRec 0 1 0 where
        pisanoRec prev cur ind
            | ind < n*n = let ncur = mod (prev + cur)  n in
                            case   (cur, ncur) of
                            (0,1) -> ind + 1
                            otherwise ->  pisanoRec cur ncur (ind + 1)
            | otherwise = 0
```

With ghci and ":set +s" I get

```hs
pisano 1953125
7812500
(9.84 secs, 3,500,053,928 bytes)
```

Why is it so long? Where is my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Changing `Integer` to `Int` (or `Word`, since you only need an unsigned type) and **compiling** with `-O` or `-O2` should considerably speed it up. (A compiled program will run faster than one in GHCi)

Comment: Yes, it's very fast (virtually instantaneous) in a compliling program, thank you.

Comment: In Vs Code (under Windows 10) Fsharp Code is compiled and the .exe is executed, that why it's so fast.

Comment: If you want to run your code from the GHCi still (without compilation that is), the way to get much more performance out of it is to set `-fobject-code` and then `-O2`.